# Run Magento 1.9.4 using PHP 7.4

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, php-7.4

I know that magento 1.9.4 will support for php7.2. Php7.2 security support will end by this year nov 2020(https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

For considering security aspect, planning to run magento 1.9.4 using php 7.4.

can we run magento 1.9.4 using php 7.4?

Please let me know (magento expert*).

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Naveen BT, Welocme to So. Does this help https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html

Comment: Magento 1.9 will support 7.2. is there any possibility to update to 7.4 because security support is going to end for 7.2.

Comment: There is [magento.se]. Maybe you should try asking there instead of here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento 1.9.x is actually compatible with PHP 7.4 if you've applied the patches that enable PHP 7.2 compatibility. I've tested it with one of the sites I host, all official patches have been applied and its running perfectly with PHP 7.4.6

Here's a preview:

[image: Magento 1.9.2.4 with PHP 7.4.6]

Comment: In 7.4 get_magic_quotes_gpc and many more functions are deprecated. Do you have list of core files which needs to be update for 7.4.

Comment: @NaveenBT  how to change array_key_exists() in magento after upgrading to php7.4

Comment: array_key_exists will support in php7.4 also

Comment: Where can I download the patch? Could I migrate my Magento 1.9.4.2 installation to Ubuntu 20.04?